# Retrieving plugin id

Tags: joomla-3.x, fix-my-code

I need to retrieve a system plugin id, and I am using the following code with success.

```
function getId($folder, $name)
    {
        // Get a database object
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();

        // Create a new query object
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);

        // Select field to get
        $fields = array(
            $db->quoteName('extension_id')
        );

        // Conditions for which record should be get
        $conditions = array(
            $db->quoteName('element') . ' = ' . $db->quote($name), 
            $db->quoteName('folder') . ' = ' . $db->quote($folder)
        );

        // Set the query and load the result
        $query->select($fields)->from($db->quoteName('#__extensions'))->where($conditions);
        $db->setQuery($query);   
        $id = $db->loadResult();

        return $id;
    }

// Set query values
$folder = 'system';
$name   = 'pugin_name';

// Get plugin id
$id = getId($folder, $name);
```

What I would like to know is if there is a better or more correct and appropriate way of doing it.

Comment: Actually a good question. I looked at `com_plugins` to see how it's done there but MVC is not my strong point. If you're familiar with it, you may find it helpful :)

Comment: there is no function available in plugin-helper or any other class which will result you this desired output. Query execution is the only way as far as I know. Couple of weeks back i done the same think in a code.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using the plugin helper

```
JPluginHelper::getPlugin('user','myplugin')->id;
```

However you'd probably want to check that getPlugin returned something before trying to access its `id` property.

This is working in 3.8.7, but I don't know when it was introduced.

Comment: I think that the ability to retrieve the plug id through the `getPlugin()` method was introduced to Joomla! 3.8.0

Answer (score 1):

This is how I get info on extensions

```
public function getItemByElement($element, $type, $folder = null)
{
    $dbo = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = $dbo->getQuery(true);
    $query->select('extension_id, manifest_cache');
    $query->from('#__extensions');

    $query->where('element = '.$dbo->quote($element));
    $query->where('type = '.$dbo->quote($type));

    if($type == 'plugin' && !empty($folder))
    {
        $query->where('folder = '.$dbo->quote($folder));
    }

    $dbo->setQuery($query);
    $extensionRecord = $dbo->loadAssoc();

    if(!is_null($extensionRecord))
    {
            $manifestData = json_decode($extensionRecord['manifest_cache']);
            $extensionRecord['manifest'] = $manifestData;
    }

    return $extensionRecord;
}
```

This will let you get anything in the extensions table

```
//return a component 
$componentData = getItemByElement('com_content', 'component');

//return a plugin
$pluginData = getItemByElement('codemirror','plugin','editors');

//return a module
$moduleData = getItemByElement('mod_article_archives', 'module');

//return library
$libData = getItemByElement('joomla','library');
```

I haven't tested it on languages (haven't had the need), but I'm sure it will work for that too.

Happy Joomla!ng =^D